# C# While loop not working as intended

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, console

I have this boss battle in my game that i'm working on for a class and its not working as intended, after the boss or the player dies it prints all sorts of attack and the death messages.

Im pretty new to code, just started this year for a class

Thanks in advance!

Here is the boss battle:

```
public static void redKeeperBattle()
    {
            if (boss.redKeeperHealth <= 0 && (player.playerHealth <= 0))
            {
                Console.Write("You have defeated ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("The Red Keeper!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("But you have also ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Died!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadLine();
                playerDeath();
            }

            if (player.playerHealth <= 0)
            {

                boss.redKeeperAlive = false;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("The Red Keeper ");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine("has killed {0}, how sad...", player.playerName);
                Console.ReadLine();
                playerDeath();
            }

            if (boss.redKeeperHealth <= 0)
            {
                boss.redKeeperAlive = false;
                Console.Write("You have defeated ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("The Red Keeper!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadLine();
                redKeeperRoom();
            }


            while (boss.redKeeperAlive == true)
            {


                //Player damage
                Random pDmg = new Random();
                int playerDmg = pDmg.Next(5, 16);

                //Player dodge
                Random pDodge = new Random();
                int playerDodge = pDodge.Next(1, 11);

                //Player crit
                Random pCrit = new Random();
                int playerCrit = pCrit.Next(10, 16);

                //Red keeper damage
                Random rDmg = new Random();
                int redDmg = rDmg.Next(1, 21);

                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("THE RED KEEPER: {0} HP", boss.redKeeperHealth);
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("{0}: ", player.playerName);
                if (player.playerHealth > 50)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                }
                else if (player.playerHealth > 20)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                }
                else {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", player.playerHealth);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
                Console.WriteLine("1) Attack");
                Console.WriteLine("2) Dodge");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.ResetColor();

                string attackChoice = Console.ReadLine();


                if (attackChoice == "1" && (playerCrit == 15))
                {
                    playerDmg += playerCrit;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.Write("You critically struck ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("The Red Keeper ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("for {0} HP!", playerDmg);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end your turn...");
                    boss.redKeeperHealth -= playerDmg;
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("The Red Keeper ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("hit you for {0}", redDmg);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end his turn...");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    player.playerHealth -= redDmg;
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    redKeeperBattle();
                }

                if (attackChoice == "1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You hit The Red Keeper for {0}", playerDmg);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end your turn...");
                    boss.redKeeperHealth -= playerDmg;
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("The Red Keeper ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("hit you for {0}", redDmg);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end his turn...");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    player.playerHealth -= redDmg;
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    redKeeperBattle();
                }

                if (attackChoice == "2" && (playerDodge > 5))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                    Console.WriteLine("You attempt to dodge!");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("You successfully dodged and gained 10 HP!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    player.playerHealth += 10;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("The Red Keeper ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("would have hit you for {0} HP!", redDmg);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    redKeeperBattle();
                }

                if (attackChoice == "2")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                    Console.WriteLine("You attempt to dodge!");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Dodge failed!");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("The Red Keeper ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("hit you for {0}", redDmg);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end his turn...");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    player.playerHealth -= redDmg;
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    redKeeperBattle();

                }
                else {

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred! Please try again!");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    redKeeperBattle();
                }

            }

    }
    public static void redKeeperRoom()
    {
        //Continue game
        Console.WriteLine ("The boss has died!");
        Console.ReadLine ();
    }


    public static void playerDeath()
    {
        //End game
        Console.WriteLine ("You have Died!");
        Console.ReadLine ();
    }
```

So what happens is when someone dies it just spams messages like:

You hit The Red Keeper for 12
Press Enter to end your turn...

The Red Keeper hit you for 14
Press Enter to end his turn...

You have defeated The Red Keeper!

The boss has died!

An error occurred! Please try again!
Press Enter to continue...

You have defeated The Red Keeper!

The boss has died!

You hit The Red Keeper for 29
Press Enter to end your turn...

The Red Keeper hit you for 19
Press Enter to end his turn...

You have defeated The Red Keeper!

But you have also Died!

You have Died!

Comment: Have you considered what happens when `redKeeperBattle()` returns given that you are calling it recursively (which you probably don't want to be doing...). i.e. `redKeeperBattle()` calls `redKeeperBattle()` which calls `redKeeperBattle()`. Now when that 3rd one returns, control is handed back to the second one. Does the second call act correctly? You could use a static int to count the call number and print some debug to tell you which call is outputting unexpected data.

Comment: :/ wall of code

Comment: Sorry @J.SMTBCJ15 I don't really know what i'm doing. :/

Comment: In your question you've not explained what you want to achieve at end of the day i.e basic theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use recursive loop and while loop, it's too complicated. It's difficult to understand what you exactly problem is.. You have to choose what to use

1) loop

```
function P(){
   while(boss.redKeeperAlive == true){

       if(condition)
          boss.redKeeperAlive = false;
   }
}
```

2) recursion

```
function P(){
       if(boss.redKeeperAlive == true){
          P()
       }
}
```

But not both in same time.

Comment: Hey thank you so much it worked! I just took out the while and used some if and else if 's and it got i done!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of the code. Since it was based on your code, it still requires more work, but some of the things I noticed are:

1. No usage of function.
2. No proper use of "if" statements.
3. No proper use of recursion and loops.

I would suggest reading up a bit more on these.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public class Boss
{
    public int redKeeperHealth = 100;
}

public class Player
{
    public int playerHealth = 100;
    public string playerName = "Ace";
}

class Program
{
    public static Boss boss = new Boss();
    public static Player player = new Player();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        redKeeperBattle();
    }

    public static void redKeeperBattle()
    {
        //Player damage
        Random pDmg = new Random();
        int playerDmg;

        //Player dodge
        Random pDodge = new Random();
        int playerDodge;

        //Player crit
        Random pCrit = new Random();
        int playerCrit;

        //Red keeper damage
        Random rDmg = new Random();
        int redDmg;

        while (boss.redKeeperHealth > 0 && player.playerHealth > 0)
        {
            PrintToScreen();
            int playerChoice = ReadPlayerChoice();

            if (playerChoice == 1)
            {
                playerDmg = pDmg.Next(5, 16);
                playerCrit = pCrit.Next(10, 16);
                if (playerCrit == 15)
                {                        
                    playerDmg += playerCrit;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.Write("You critically struck ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("You hit The Red Keeper for {0}", playerDmg);
                boss.redKeeperHealth -= playerDmg;

                redDmg = rDmg.Next(1, 21);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("The Red Keeper ");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine("hit you for {0}", redDmg);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                redDmg = rDmg.Next(1, 21);
                player.playerHealth -= redDmg;

                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.ResetColor();                    
            }

            else if (playerChoice == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                Console.WriteLine("You attempt to dodge!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadLine();

                playerDodge = pDodge.Next(1, 11);
                if (playerDodge > 5)
                {
                    redDmg = rDmg.Next(1, 21);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("You successfully dodged and gained 10 HP!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    player.playerHealth += 10;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("The Red Keeper ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("would have hit you for {0} HP!", redDmg);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    redDmg = rDmg.Next(1, 21);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Dodge failed!");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("The Red Keeper ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("hit you for {0}", redDmg);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end his turn...");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    player.playerHealth -= redDmg;
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

            }                
            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred! Please try again!");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }


            if (boss.redKeeperHealth <= 0 && player.playerHealth <= 0)
            {
                Console.Write("You have defeated ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("The Red Keeper!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("But you have also ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Died!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadLine();
                playerDeath();
            }

            if (player.playerHealth <= 0 && boss.redKeeperHealth > 0)
            {

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("The Red Keeper ");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine("has killed {0}, how sad...", player.playerName);
                Console.ReadLine();
                playerDeath();
            }

            if (boss.redKeeperHealth <= 0 && player.playerHealth > 0)
            {
                Console.Write("You have defeated ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("The Red Keeper!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadLine();
                redKeeperRoom();
            }

        }

    }
    public static void redKeeperRoom()
    {
        //Continue game
        Console.WriteLine("The boss has died!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static void playerDeath()
    {
        //End game
        Console.WriteLine("You have Died!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintToScreen()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("THE RED KEEPER: {0} HP", boss.redKeeperHealth);
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("{0}: ", player.playerName);
        if (player.playerHealth > 50)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        }
        else if (player.playerHealth > 20)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", player.playerHealth);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Attack");
        Console.WriteLine("2) Dodge");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    private static int ReadPlayerChoice()
    {
        return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

}

-Enjoy